# what is $block->getchildhtml() in topmenu.phml file

Tags: magento2.3

I was trying to do/learn something and i am at topmenu.phtml file , i have seen $block->getchildhtml() there and when i go to block which is 
namespace Magento\Theme\Block\Html; with the name topmenu.php , i am not seeing any getchildhtml function there . I did research on what getchildhtml function is i have realized it is comming from the layout but when i go to layout which is default.xml file in the module-theme folder there is

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="store.menu" group="navigation-sections" template="Magento_Theme::html/container.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Menu</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="Magento_Theme::html/topmenu.phtml" ttl="3600" before="-"/>
</block>
```

there is no child of this block so from where this getchildhtml will see and print result ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$block->getChildHtml()
```

will return child block html. So in your case create child block using xml, this code snippet will automatically return html of that child block. Ex.

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="store.menu" group="navigation-sections" template="Magento_Theme::html/container.phtml">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Menu</argument>
    </arguments>
    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="Magento_Theme::html/topmenu.phtml" ttl="3600" before="-">
        <block name="sample.testblock" template="Vendor_Module::sample.phtml"/>
    </block>
</block>
```

**<block name="sample.testblock" template="Vendor_Module::sample.phtml"/>** block will render automatically.